# Unable to align ForEach to conform to leading aligment

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I have the following code:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 3) {
        Text("Hours")
            .font(.body.weight(.bold))
    }
    ScrollViewIfNeeded(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
        Group {
            if item.hours != [] || !item.hours.isEmpty {
                ForEach(item.hours, id: \.self) { hour in
                    Text(hour)
                }
            } else {
                Text("No hours provided.")
            }
        }
        .font(.footnote)
        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
    }
}
.frame(width: containerWidth * 0.40)
```

Which won't conform to the `.leading` modifiers at all - The items are currently centered in the view.

If I remove the ForEach statement and just place multiple regular `Text("..")` calls, it works just fine and aligns to the left, similar to this:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
    HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 3) {
        Text("Hours")
            .font(.body.weight(.bold))
    }
    ScrollViewIfNeeded(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
        Group {

            Text("Hello1")
            Text("Hello2")
            Text("Hello3")

        }
        .font(.footnote)
        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
    }
}
.frame(width: containerWidth * 0.40)
```

The above works just fine and aligns to the left.

Does anyone know what difference ForEach statements have with alignment?

---

Update:

`let item: Place` <- Definition of item.

```
struct Place: Codable, Identifiable {
    var hours = [String]()
    
    // MARK: - SET DEFAULT PROPERTIES
    static var `default` : Place {
        Place(
            hours: ("Hours")
        )
    }
    
    init(
        hours: (String)
    ) {
        self.hours = [hours]
    }
    
    init(with p: MGLocation) {
        self.hours = p.hours ?? []
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the definition of `item`?

Comment: @Will, it's defined as `[String]` and in the database it is shown as: `["Monday 6AM–11PM","Tuesday 6AM–11PM","Wednesday 6AM–11PM","Thursday 6AM–11PM","Friday 6AM–11PM","Saturday 6AM–11PM","Sunday 6AM–11PM"]`

Comment: I just updated the code at the bottom to show `item: Place`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, weird enough, you have to pass a VStack inside a ScrollView, regardless if you have a VStack defined outside the ScrollView:

```
ScrollViewIfNeeded(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
    Group {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            if item.hours != [] || !item.hours.isEmpty {
                ForEach(item.hours, id: \.self) { hour in
                    Text(hour)
                }
                .frame(alignment: .topLeading)
            } else {
                Text("No hours provided.")
            }
        }
    }
    .font(.footnote)
    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
}
```

Odd, but it works!